# Fixed points theorem applications

Tags: real-analysis

I want to find the number of solutions to the equation $\cos x=x^2$ in the closed interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

My approach to the question was to draw the graph of both these functions and see the point of their intersection.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You need to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Did you do that?   Were you able to count the intersections?  Why do you need to ask us about this?

Comment: Yes i got it as 2

Comment: Hint: Consider the function $f(x)=x^2-\cos x$. Note that this function is even, and hence it is enough to consider its root on $[0, \pi/2]$. Then note that $f'(x)=2x+\sin x>0$ on $(0,\pi/2]$, while $f(0)<0$ but $f(\pi/2)>0$. Therefore, there is a unique root for $f$ on $[0, \pi/2]$ (using continuity). Then, since $f$ is even, there is a unique solution on $[-\pi/2, 0]$. In total, there are two intersections, as you found by graphing.

Comment: Thnku user65018

Answer (score 2):

Define $f\colon \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = x^2 - \cos x$. You want to know how many zeroes $f$ has.

- $f$ is an even function.
- $f$ is differentiable, and $f^\prime(x) = 2x + \sin x$.
- $\sin > 0$ on $\left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$
- $f(0) = -1$, and $f(\frac{\pi}{2}) >0$. (Think *Intermediate Value Theorem* now.)

Can you conclude from there?